# What does `git checkout ...` do?

Tags: git

I occasionally accidentally write `git checkout ...`, which puts me into a detached head state. I was wondering why. Here's the "dot story":

```
> git checkout .
# checks out current directory
> git checkout ..
# Checks out parent directory, if in repository.
> git checkout ...
# Puts into detached head state?
> git checkout ....
error: pathspec '....' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is a degenerate form of this syntax, described in the `gitrevisions(7)` man page:

```
   <rev1>...<rev2>
       Include commits that are reachable from either <rev1> or <rev2> but
       exclude those that are reachable from both. When either <rev1> or
       <rev2> is omitted, it defaults to HEAD.
```

Note that last bit, "When either `<rev1>` or `<rev2>` is omitted, it defaults to HEAD".  That means that writing `...` is equivalent to `HEAD...HEAD`.  When used in `git checkout` this ends up evaluating to the commit id of HEAD.  That is, you're just doing:

```
git checkout HEAD^{commit}
```

Comment: This is correct, but there's a bit of subtlety as well: Git implements this in a function named `get_oid_mb` where `mb` stands for Merge Base. It literally checks for the three dot `...` notation and when that's present, parses the two revs on either side (or uses `HEAD` as noted) and then, in effect, runs `git merge-base --all <rev1> <rev2>` to get the merge bases. If there is exactly one such merge base, that's the commit; otherwise the `...` fails to resolve.

Comment: The `git diff` command used to use the same trick: `git diff A...B` means `git diff $(git merge-base A B) B`, and I think maybe the code was shared. Now `git checkout` is the only user of `get_oid_mb`. All other cases treat it as described in the documentation, i.e., don't actually run the equivalent of `git merge-base --all`.

Comment: (BTW when I say "all other" I mean "all except `git checkout` and `git diff`. The code in `git diff` uses the internal version of what you see if you run `git rev-parse`: try running a literal `git rev-parse ...`, for instance. But `git diff` then transforms the positive and negative reference set, in a currently-slightly-broken way, that works well if there's one merge base.)